# Query to flatten Employee Hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy

I am just 2yrs experienced in SQL, and trying to flatten hierarchy from below table, not getting through. Appreciate your valuable suggestions.

Requirement is to show something like `'bala>>ben>>mari>>dir>>cto>>ceo>>null'`

I tried this, but no luck.

```
declare @cn varchar(25), @mn varchar(25), @vr varchar(25), @tm varchar(25), @msg varchar(max);
declare crsr cursor for
select * from dbo.ctable ct order by ename
open crsr
fetch next from crsr into @cn, @mn
set @msg = @cn
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
 if @mn is not null set @msg = @msg + ' - '+@mn
 print @msg
 fetch next from crsr into @cn, @mn
end
close crsr
deallocate crsr
```

[image: Data table looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

I got to frame this simple query, sufficing my requirement. Hope this can be fine tuned further, will be a great help. Thnx

```
select c.ename Emp, c.mname Lvl1, isnull(c1.mname,'') Lvl2, 
isnull(c2.mname,'') Lvl3,isnull(c3.mname,'') Lvl4,isnull(c4.mname,'') 
Lvl5,isnull(c5.mname,'') Lvl6
,c.ename+' >> '+c.mname+' >> '+isnull(c1.mname,'')+' >> 
'+isnull(c2.mname,'')+' >> '+isnull(c3.mname,'')+' >> 
'+isnull(c4.mname,'')+' >> '+isnull(c5.mname,'')
from ctable c
left join ctable c1 on c.mname=c1.ename
left join ctable c2 on c1.mname=c2.ename
left join ctable c3 on c2.mname=c3.ename
left join ctable c4 on c3.mname=c4.ename
left join ctable c5 on c4.mname=c5.ename
left join ctable c6 on c5.mname=c6.ename
```